# Algebraic proof for paraboles

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am asked to prove that the parabole $y=ax^2+bx+c$ has a chord that passes through the points where $x=a$ and $y=b$ (individually, I suppose, otherwise they would be both the same point), and that chord is parallel to the tangent in $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$.

I got only the easy (or evident) part, being the slope at $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$ equals to $a(a+b)+b$.

I then took the points $P_1(a, a^3+ab+c)$ and $P_2(x, b)$ to try to get the slope of the chord, but when getting $x$ in $P_2$, I see that it is an implicit equation and it can't be done that way:

$b=ax^2+bx+c$

$ax^2+bx=b-c$

$x(ax+b)=b-c$

$x=\frac{b-c}{ax+b}$

And no more else. Now I am stuck and I have no idea on how to do this. Can you explain to me?

Comment: I don't get you clear. $a=1$ $b=0$ $c=1$ I guess.

Comment: Or is it $sqrt(y-1)$?

Comment: You say a chord that passes through some points, but you never say what points. $x=a$ and $y=b$ are lines, not points

Comment: I am sorry. The points described in the original problem are the points where $x=a$ in $P_1$ and $y=b$ in $P_2$. Those are supposed to be points in the parabole.

Comment: Then the problem is wrongly formulated?

Comment: Could you please write the original statement of the problem (even in spanish)

Comment: You guessed... "Probar que la parábola y = Ax^2 + Bx + C, la cuerda que une los puntos para los cuales x = a y y = b es paralela a la tangente en el punto para el cual x = (a + b)/2.
"

Comment: The question is not very well written in the part where it says "la cuerda", so I modified it a little.

Comment: Probably it should be $x=a$ and $x=b$

Comment: Yes it makes more sense. I will try with that.

Comment: Yes, effectively. With the points where $x=a$ and $x=b$, the line is parallel to the tangent in $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Well done! Please edit your question and write also your solution

Comment: Hi :) you just have to prove $\frac{f(s)-f(t)}{s-t}=f'(\frac{s+t}{2}) $ for all $s, t\in\mathbb R$ and $f\in\mathbb R[x]$ with $\deg(f) \leq 2$.

Comment: Ohh, like the Intermediate Value Theorem?